# NUXT VUE Transition in component when leaving page

Tags: vue.js, transition, nuxt.js

I got the following setup in nuxt

- page/blog/index.vue
- components/topheader.vue

I would like to have transition effect when you leave a page and enter the page in the component topheader. The title should fadein/fadeout. This because now the title is replaced very abrupt without a transition effect.

The problem is when you go to a new page/route the animation has no time to go ahead. So I have some success with stopping the the router with beforeRouteLeave then pass a prop "showTitle" to the component setting it to false. Set a timeout on the next() in beforeLeave ...
But this feels quite wrong and bad practice

I Looked in to setting in nuxt.conf transition. But this is for the a page transition and has only an effect on the complete page. It seems I can't target something in a component only there. My feeling is I should be able to do this with some setting there. However I'm missing something.

For appearing the transition I can use  ...

Now my question. How to target something in a component of a page to create a transition on leaving the page. Ideal the loading is already started so the transition takes about the time between the page loads.

thx in advance

Answer (score -1):

You can  wrap your component with the `<transition name="yourTransitionName"></transition>` tag.

In CSS:

`.yourTransitionName-leave-active {
  /* your code */
}`